# Azure Communication Services (Calling SDK) - How many video streams are supported?

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

I am very confused about the calling sdk specs. They are clear about the fact that only one video stream can be rendered at one time [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/calling-sdk-features)...
BUT when I try out the following [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-tutorial) I get video streams for all members of the group call. When I try the other [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-web-calling-hero/issues/new) (both from ms), it behaves like written in the specs... So I am totally confused here why this other example can render more than one video stream in parallel? Can anybody tell me how to understand this? Is it possible or not?

EDIT: I found out that both examples work with multiple videos streams. So it is cool that the service provide more than the specs say, but I do not get the point why the specs tell about that not existing limitations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one video stream is supported on ACS Web (JS) calling SDK, multiple video stream can be rendered for incoming calls but A/V quality is not guaranteed at this stage for more than one video. Support for 4(2x2) and 9(3x3) is on the roadmap and we'll publish support as network bandwidth paired with quality assurance testing and verification is identified and completed.